# Android - Get shape color/solid in a drawable

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I want to get the color of a shape stored in an xml file drawable.

I came to the step that I have the Drawable stored in a Drawable variable, so, now I'd like to get the color (solid tag) of the shape.

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697407/get-a-textview-background-color-with-shapedrawable

Answer (score 3):

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)view.getBackground();
Class<? extends GradientDrawable> aClass = gradientDrawable.getClass();
try {
    Field mFillPaint = aClass.getDeclaredField("mFillPaint");
    mFillPaint.setAccessible(true);
    Paint strokePaint= (Paint) mFillPaint.get(gradientDrawable);
    int solidColor = strokePaint.getColor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think the ***solidColor*** is you want to get.