# Get a textView background color with ShapeDrawable

Tags: android, textview, background-color, shapedrawable

I have a textview with the background defined in a xml file.

```
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/event_tvColor"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="   "
            android:background="@drawable/et_style_color_service_edit"
            android:clickable="true"
          />

           xml file :  et_style_color_service_edit.xml

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                    android:shape="oval">        
                 <solid android:color="@color/eventColor"/>
                 <stroke android:width="0sp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
                 <size android:width="20dp"
                       android:height="20dp"/>
              </shape>
```

And i need to get the color that the view have in a one time.

```
 ShapeDrawable sc = (ShapeDrawable)tvColor.getBackground();
  ...............
```

Note that i need to use ShapeDrawable and not GradientDrawable.
Thank you for your help and time.

Solution........

```
        Solution The xml loads into the app as a gradientdrawable and not as a shapedrawable. We have to define the shapeDrawable in java 

          ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape);  
          sd.getPaint().setColor(0xFF0000FF);
```

if anyone have a better solution can tell.

Answer (score 4):

After further research, there currently is no way of getting the xml loaded ShapeDrawable's color. What you have to do is just track your color changes so you know what color you are setting it to, ie:

```
int currentColor = Color.WHITE; //this is the default color (color set in xml)

public void changeColor() {
    if (currentColor == Color.WHITE) {
        currentColor = Color.BLUE;
    } else {
        currentColor = Color.WHITE;
    }
    GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable)tvColor.getBackground();
    gd.setColor(currentColor);
}
```

Comment: Hello Zed Scio. Thanks for your reply. I try ShapeDrawable sc = (ShapeDrawable)tvColor.getBackground();
 int color = sc.getPaint().getColor(); . But give me an error. java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable ...And i don´t understand becausa the element <shape> in xml file serve to shapeDrawable and gradient drawable ..... any idea Zed?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066892/how-to-import-shape-resourcexml-to-code, xml <shape> loads into the app as a gradientdrawable. My suggestion is to make the ShapeDrawable in java and then set it to the EditText

Comment: I don't understant "Make the shapeDrawable in java". You can give me an example zed scio? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Solution
The xml loads into the app as a gradientdrawable and not as a shapedrawable.
We have to define the shapeDrawable in java
ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape); sd.getPaint().setColor(0xFF0000FF);
if anyone have a better solution can tell....